Как заменить h3 на span в вордпрессе через файл function.php?
Прошу помочь. Есть сайт, wordpress + woocommerce,
Внизу многих продуктов, есть секция с похожими продуктами. Названия этих похожих продуктов, обврнуты в заголовок h3, как этот заголовок можно заменить на span?
Вот пример страницы:
https://evroflag.by/product/roll-up-stands
Вот надписи, которые обвёрнуты в h3 и которые надо заменить на span.


Наверное, тут будет логичнее внести изменение в шаблон, чем делать подмену тега

Правильно - это сделать дочернюю (child) тему, в ней создать папку "woocommerce" в которую из самого woocommerce скопировать шаблоны того, что ты будешь менять. Это по фен-шую. Я и сам так делал - так работает корректно. В папке плагинов есть сам плагин woocommerce и уже в нём есть templates, в которой находятся шаблоны для разных элементов. Ещё есть тонкость. Важно какой шаблон вы используете, поскольку некоторые шаблоны переопределяют дизайн и логику Woocommerce. Сначала посмотрите настройки шаблона.
UPD: Посмотрел. У Вас шаблон WoodMart, там море настроек для WooCommerce. Вероятно есть возможность сделать стилистику без смены тега.

Кстати, попробовал разобраться с WoodMart шаблоном, поискал логику и взаимосвязи - крайне запутанная структура. Много возможностей и много шаблонов и подшаблонов на все случаи жизни. Самое странное, h3 в стандартном шаблоне для related нет. Может ли быть, что шаблон уже дорабатывали? Если нет, то смотреть настройки в админке woodmart. Опять же, сами темы и плагины от версии к версии меняются, так что надо смотреть по месту.
